# When to use equality ("==") instead of identity ("===")?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Javascript === vs == : Does it matter which “equal” operator I use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/javascript-vs-does-it-matter-which-equal-operator-i-use)

Many recommend using `===` for comparison everywhere in your JavaScript instead of `==`, and it sounds reasonable.

I was wondering are there any situations where using `==` would be actually beneficial over `===`?

Comment: People who vote up duplicate comments should be arrested.

Comment: @Josh: Not necessarily.  Many's the time I've seen a question closed because it had a superficial resemblance to some other question, but with a new wrinkle or better phrasing (better searchability).  Once a question is closed, no matter how wrongly, it is very rarely reopened (SO bias/flaw) -- so upvotes let us see that it has merit despite being closed.   PS: I am *not* saying that this particular question is not close-worthy.

Comment: @Roatin I didn't end my sentence with a period :P